# Adding options to backbone.js model.save()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

Is it possible to pass inside the options of the "save" method - a diffrent url/path for the request ?

The default urlRot for the model is --> `urlRoot: "/users"`

is it possible to do something like that:

```
this.model.save({
           'userName': $('#userName').val(),
           'password': $('#password').val()},{

            url: "/users/login",

            success: function(model, response, options) {

            },
```

So the request, this time, will be sent to "/users/login" and NOT to "/users" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url):

> urlmodel.url()
>
> Returns the relative URL where the model's resource
>   would be located on the server. If your models are located somewhere
>   else, override this method with the correct logic. Generates URLs of
>   the form: "/[collection.url]/[id]", falling back to "/[urlRoot]/id" if
>   the model is not part of a collection.

So it looks as if you can provide your own `url` function on a model.

Example:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    use_custom_url: false,
    url: function() {
        if (use_custom_url) {
            return "/users/login";
        } else {
            return Backbone.Model.prototype.url.apply(this);
        }
    }
});
```